# disabling Privacy, Device permissions and device access

Tags: android, permissions, device

I've recently created an app which is basically a webview component that displays a website, when I want to install the app on an android phone (havent tried on iOS yet) the privacy setting and device permissions/access you have to agree with are far more than what the app requires, if it is a simple webview app it should not need access to anything other than full network access, however other requirements that you have to agree with before installing the app are "read contacts, read texts, make calls, send texts... etc." it pretty much requires all the possible device permissions that there is, and so some people might not want to install the app due to this reason. Is there any way I can cancel or disable the device access/permissions that the app requires?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need [more to go on](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than what you have provided. In particular, please post your manifest and, if you are using Android Studio, the `build.gradle` file where you are pulling in any libraries that your app uses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Commonsware, I'm using Smartface app studio to create the app, after checking the manifest file I realised that the settings can be changed there! thanks for the help.